# How to find integer solution of a rational function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If we have a function $f(z)={{P(x,y)}\over{Q(x,y)}}$ and the goal what to solve for integer values of $z$, how would someone solve such problem?

Comment: Wait, is $z=(x,y)?$

Comment: it is, but it needs to be an integer

Comment: There are a number of approaches, but they depend on the forms of the functions involved.  All the factors of $Q(x,y)$ have to also be factors of $P(x,y)$, you can't have irrational square roots, etc.

Comment: can you show me different examples, with the different cases?

Comment: As it stands, the question is way too broad. How about **you** giving us an example to solve?

Comment: For example if you've got ${4(3+xy)}\over{y + x} $